# Specify return type of constructor of class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make class that implements Date Object but make some difference in a way where Date parses string argument without "Z" in the end like `new Date("2022-01-01T00:00:00")`.

I succeed in making class that works well, but I want to make the variable that is made by this class inferred as `Date`, not `LocalDate`
.

I tried making interface of it but failed. Have any idea to specify the return type of constructor?

(I want to remain class structure - not a function structure)

```
class LocalDate extends Date {
  constructor(value: number | string | Date);
  constructor(
    year: number,
    month: number,
    date?: number,
    hours?: number,
    minutes?: number,
    seconds?: number,
    ms?: number,
  );
  constructor(...args: any[]) {
    if (!args?.length) {
      super();
    } else if (args?.length === 1) {
      const value = args[0];
      typeof value === 'string' && !value.endsWith('Z') && !!new Date(value)
        ? super(
            new Date(value + 'Z').getTime() +
              new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * MINUTE_AS_MILLISECOND,
          )
        : super(value);
    } else {
      super(args[0], args[1], ...args.slice(1));
    }
  }
}

const VARIABLE = new LocalDate() // I want this to be inferred as Date
```

Comment: It's very bad practice for a constructor to not return an instance of itself. You are probably looking for a factory here.

Comment: Also, why should it matter which object you get back? Ideally, you should be programming to *an interface* and the implementation behind it doesn't matter. If you need *specific implementation*, then you don't actually have generic objects. In the case you've shown, I really don't see why `Date` vs `LocalDate` would matter. Moreover, the result would never actually be `Date` - it's always `LocalDate` as the constructor only returns instances of its own class here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a class constructor returning a different type than its class is not just a very bad practice in TypeScript, it is actually *impossible by design*:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#constructors

> Constructors can’t have return type annotations - the class instance type is always what’s returned

Comment: No it's not a bad practice inherently in JavaScript nor TypeScript. Constructors, like their prototypal functions they build upon, can opt to return a type of object that augments the instance (or anything, really).

So, for example, a class constructor could return a Proxy of itself, which is a perfectly normal and legitimate thing to do, making this a very stupid part of TypeScript.